# Binomial distribution calculate probability of pikes - is my solution correct?

Tags: probability, statistics, binomial-distribution

In a lake, there are two types of fish: trouts and pikes. Let p = 0.7 be the proportion of trouts in the lake. We pick 20 fish at random with replacement. Let X be the number of trouts.

a) What distribution would correspond to the number of trouts obtained? What is the formula for P(X=k)?

b) What is the probability that we get 18 pikes.

> a) I am thinking since we are having sampling with replacement, that the distribution is Binomial. From here on, the formula for $P(k) = \binom{n}{k} p^k(1-p)^{n - k}$
>
> b) Since the proportion of trouts is p=0.7, the proportion of pikes in the lake is 0.3. Here k=18 and n=20, so we substitute in the formula above and get: P(18)= 0.000000036. 
>   The result was obtained by using: $P(18) = \binom{20}{18} 0.3^{18}0.7^{2}$

This incredible low probability number is rather worrying me and since I don't have the solved solution to compare with a correct answer, I'm asking here if this looks correct or if I messed something up big time?

Thank you in advance for your time and help!

Comment: How did you obtain your result?

Comment: By P(18) = 20 choose 18 x 0.3 on the 18th x 0.3 on the 2nd. Unsure if formulas work here.

Comment: It looks correct to me.

Comment: Thank you @DavidPM